# What does the author of each method shown by Visual Studio mean?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2015 shows the author of each method in C# programs, for example

```
2 references | tom, 100 days ago | 1 author, 1 change
private void MyMethod()
{
}
```

But Tom said that he didn't write the method, and Visual Studio seemed to have a problem with determining the authors of a method after a merge. Note that we push and pull from a repository on Github.

So what does the author of each method shown by Visual Studio mean?

Comment: You can always go look at the history in your source control (you can also right click -> source control -> annotate and see who last modified that code).

Comment: How can i find out which  plugin? @Claies

Comment: Unless you change it, it will be the Microsoft Git Provider. Just look at the annotated version and/or the history.

Comment: I have a bit more trust in git showing correct commit\merge author than in Tom remembering what he did.

Comment: @Claies This is not an external plugin.  Microsoft Git Provider is built-into VS2015 and provides information from git in CodeLens annotations.

Answer (score 4):

It shows the last person to make any change to it. Initially, that would be the original author. After that, it's whoever last made any change.

Comment: Thanks. But Visual Studio said that Tom is the only author, and he said he didn't write the method.

Comment: Did Tom commit/merge it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the merge and the compilation was done on the enviroment of TOM for this reason you see the Tom name  as the author you  should see the all history in order to determine the real author. we have got the same issue but when we look at the history we find the real author.

This [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/history) explains how to find history

Comment: Where do you find the history?

Comment: in the file, right click -> source control -> view history

Comment: I have uptaded my answer