# For a given line in a file, can I find out which commit last changed/created it? Thanks

Tags: git

For a given line (or any given unit of text) in a file, can I find out which commit last changed/created it?

This will help me to identify who last changed/created it, based on the commit.

[Visual Studio 2015 for C# seems to have such feature.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587631/what-does-the-author-of-each-method-shown-by-visual-studio-mean) I guess it uses git to do that. Also some commentator said that "I have a bit more trust in git showing correct commit\merge author than in Tom remembering what he did."

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: discover which commits ever touched a range of lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142609/git-discover-which-commits-ever-touched-a-range-of-lines)

Answer (score 1):

### `git blame -L`

```
# Here -L100,+10 means "only look at the lines 100 to 100+11":
git blame -L100,+10 -- git-web--browse.sh
```

> `-L <start>,<end>`
>     `-L :<funcname>`
>
> Annotate **only the given line range**.
>   May be specified multiple times. Overlapping ranges are allowed.
>
> `<start>` and `<end>` are optional. `-L <start>` or `-L <start>,` spans from `<start>` to end of file.
>
> `-L ,<end>` spans from start of file to `<end>`.